Symmetric difference of Shannon's entropy satisfies triangle inequality
For random variables $X$ and $Y$, we define:
$$\delta(X,Y) = H(X|Y) + H(Y|X)$$
Show that $\delta(X,Y)$ satisfies the triangle inequality.
My attempt: I tried to write $H(X|Y) = H(X,Y) - H(Y)$, then I got:
$$H(X,Y) + H(Y,Z) - H(X,Z) - H(Y) >=0$$
But then I got stuck as I do not know how to proceed. I guess I need some tricks to put it into the right form, but I just don't know how to do this. Any hint or help is greatly appreciated.

The question is if for any $(X,Y,Z),$
$$ H(Z|X) + H(X|Z) + H(Y|Z) + H(Z|Y) \overset?\ge H(X|Y) + H(Y|X).$$
As you noticed, by writing $H(U|V) = H(U,V) - H(V),$ this is equivalent to $$ H(X,Z) + H(Y,Z)  \overset{?}\ge H(X,Y) + H(Z)  $$
Now, we can further write $H(X,Z) = H(X,Y,Z) - H(Y|X,Z)$, and the question becomes equivalent to $$ H(X,Y,Z) + H(Z|X,Y) \overset?\ge H(X|Y,Z) + H(Y|X,Z) + H(Z) $$ But we know that $$ H(X,Y,Z) = H(Z) + H(X|Z) + H(Y|X,Z) \ge H(Z) + H(X|Y,Z) + H(Y|X,Z),$$ since conditioning reduces entropy, and we're done.

thank you very much!
